# How the ThingsBoard web socket is working and parsing data to front end

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, open-source, thingsboard

Can someone explained how the web socket connection established in the ThingsBoard and where the stored data and parsing the stored data into the front end time series widget real time. Please find the below git hub open source repository link for your reference.

https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard

I have tried to  cloned this source code and run in the local environment and I wouldn't  be able to run due to the below mentioned some dependency issue.

org.thingsboard.server.gen.transport.TransportProtos

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.thingsboard:gradle-maven-plugin:1.0.11:invoke (default) on project http: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip'. -> [Help 1]